# what does set mean in pandas df group by fun

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm new to pandas DF.

I cant understand the code inside agg . I get this is group by and agg like pyspark DF. But what does for i in set(x) mean?

Where did the set(x) come from what is pd.isNull(i)?is it just a null checker?

```
newDF = existing.groupby(["cols"]).agg(
    new_col1=pd.NamedAgg(column='ColA', aggfunc=lambda x: [i.split(':')[0] for i in set(x) if not pd.isnull(i)]),
    ColA=pd.NamedAgg(column='ColA', aggfunc=lambda x: [i for i in set(x) if not pd.isnull(i)]),
    ColC=pd.NamedAgg(column='ColB', aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join([i if not pd.isnull(i) else 'Good' for i in set(x)])),
    ColE=pd.NamedAgg(column='ColD', aggfunc=lambda x: ', '.join([i if not pd.isnull(i) else 'Good' for i in set(x)]), ))
```

Please help me with this

Comment: `set(x)` comes from... well, exactly where it appears. `x` is the argument to the `lambda` function, and it's being converted to a `set` right then and there in the list comprehension. `set()` is a [builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) to get a [fundamental python data structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) that has nothing to do with `pandas` in particular

Comment: `set` there is used to look at only unique values of the group. `pd.isnull` is indeed the null checker but `not pd.isnull(val)` is a bad way of writing `pd.notnull(val)` or `pd.notna(val)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python sets are mutable unordered collections of unique elements.
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
lst = [1, 2, 2, 3, np.NaN, 3, 3]
a = pd.Series(data=lst)
b = set(a)
c = [i if not pd.isnull(i) else 'Good' for i in set(a)]

print(a)

0    1.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    3.0
6    3.0

print(b)

{nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}

print(c)

['Good', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example could illustrate the explanations given in the comments. With a DataFrame -

```
   cols  ColA  ColB
0     1   1.0    11
1     2   3.0    12
2     2   3.0    23
3     3   2.0    24
4     4   5.0    25
5     3   6.0    26
6     1   5.0    27
7     2   NaN    28
```

and using

```
newDF = df.groupby(["cols"]).agg(ColA=pd.NamedAgg(column='ColA', aggfunc = lambda x: [i for i in set(x) if not pd.isnull(i)]))
```

you would get:

```
            ColA
cols            
1     [1.0, 7.0]
2          [3.0]
3     [2.0, 6.0]
4          [5.0]
```

which shows the set(x) and isnull() operations working as already explained in the comments.